# how to execute catch block for code coverage in mockito?

Tags: springmockito

i am tying to execute catch block in order to achieve 90% sonar coverage. Here is the code

---

```
public Map<Integer, Triplet<Integer, Integer, Integer>> getResult(int num1, List<Integer> numbers) {
    List<Triplet<Integer, Integer, Integer>> result;
    try {
        result = innerMethod(Util.getRes(num1), num1, numbers);
        return result;
    }

}
```

i tried the below approach,

```
public void ExcepTest(){
    //Tried method 1
    when(mockObj.getResult(anyInt(),anyList())).thenThrow(mock(Exception.class));
    //Tried method 2
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mockObj).getResult(anyInt(),anyList());
    //Tried method 3
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mockObj.getResult(anyInt(),anyList()));

}
```

it throws invocationTaget exception instead going to that catch block. And in that innerMethod some DB connections are there with try-catch block.

How to execute that catch block? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: Just call _getResult(null, null)_ and I suppose your DB call will throw exception which will be intercepted in calling method!

Comment: Thanks Gokul. It is working..